# Update query not actually updating

Tags: php, sql, json, mysqli

I've been trying to fix a problem I've been having with my MySQLi class. It executes an update query, but it doesn't actually update. It tells me one row has been affected, but in reality nothing has changed.

This is my code for executing queries:

```
class database_model {

private $mysqli = null;

private $hostname = '127.0.0.1';
private $username = 'root';
private $password = 'password';
private $database = 'database';

public function __construct()
{
    $this->mysqli = new mysqli($this->hostname, $this->username, $this->password, $this->database);
    if ($this->mysqli->connect_errno) {
        die('Failed to connect to MySQL: (' . $this->mysqli->connect_errno . ') ' . $this->mysqli->connect_error);
    }
}

public function query($query, $parameters)
{
    $stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare($query);

    if (is_array($parameters)) {            
        call_user_func_array('mysqli_stmt_bind_param', array_merge(array($stmt, str_repeat('s', count($parameters))), $this->makeValuesReferenced($parameters))); 
    } else {
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $parameters);
    }

    $stmt->execute();

    $results = $stmt->get_result();
    $this->mysqli->commit();
    $stmt->close();

    return $results;
}

private function makeValuesReferenced(&$arr)
{
    $refs = array();
    foreach($arr as $key => $value) {
        $refs[$key] = &$arr[$key];
    }

    return $refs;
}
}
```

For clarification, the makeValuesReferenced and call_user_func_array are used to dynamically bind parameters to the query.

I have turned on error reporting.

Some other things that might be worth noting. The update query is called from a static function, but the values are correct inside the query function. The code calling the query function looks like this:

```
$session_query = 'UPDATE session SET data = ? WHERE session.user = ?';
self::$db->query($session_query, array($json_data,
                                       self::$credential_value));

$json_data example value: {"dialog_choices":[["Companion","Start searching",3,1]]}
value after updating to $json_data: {"dialog_choices":[["Companion","Start searching",3,1]],"data_encounter":{"id":0}}
```

It remains unchanged

```
self::$credential_value corresponds to the right "session.user".
```

I'm at a loss here, I have tried many different variations thinking it might be a commit or escape issue, but it seemed to be neither.

Sincerely Yours,
Nick

Comment: Why do you use `call_user_func_array`? `mysqli` has methods that are perfectly capable of doing this...

Comment: Have you tried executing the resulting query manually to ensure that it's correct? The other possibility is that the table is locked and the request never gets processed.

Comment: Remove the `WHERE` part and try the query like `UPDATE session SET data = ?`. Most probably the `where` condition is not matching any row.

Comment: @CommuSoft I did not find any alternative, care to share?
ventsyv, Manually executing the code actually changes the row.
rahul, The where clause is correct and it tells me one row has been affected.